# Text substitution depending on the length of the group matched

Tags: python, python-re

**Background:** Absolute beginner working through the book "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" and was curious as to how to make this substitution:

**Input string:**

```
"Agent Alice tells Agent Bob secret info about Agent Charlie."
```

**Desired Output:**

```
"Agent A**** tells Agent B** secret info about Agent C******."
```

Note how the number of asterisks depends on the length of the name.

**What I've tried:**

```
import re
concealName = re.compile(r'(Agent)(\s)(\w)(\w)*')
sentence = "Agent Alice tells Agent Bob secret info about Agent Charlie."  
concealName.sub(r'\1\2\3' + '*' * len(r'\4'), sentence)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
'Agent A** gave Agent B** info about Agent C**'
```

My logic was that it would calculate the length of each instance of a matched group 4, and multiply that length with the '*' string, which should've resulted in a string of ****** with the same length as the group 4 matched.
Completely clueless as to why this didn't work, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because what you pass to `sub` is essentially a template string. It gets passed to the internals of the function and only then do the back-references get replaced with the real thing.

That is, `r'\1\2\3' + '*' * len(r'\4')` is *first* evaluated into `r'\1\2\3' + '*' * 2` (the length of literal `\4`) and then into `r'\1\2\3**'`, so the reference `\4` is lost and you always end up with the first character of group 3 followed by two `**`.

Even if it worked that way, you got an error in your original pattern: The last part should be `(\w*)` with the asterisk *within* the group, otherwise it would repeat the whole group and `\4` would only ever capture one single character.

Ultimately, however, I think you will have to use a different approach, i.e., by passing a function to `sub`. The closest to your solution is this:

```py
import re

sentence = "Agent Alice tells Agent Bob secret info about Agent Charlie."

# note the * at the end - try to move it outside the group and see what happens!
concealName = re.compile(r'(Agent)(\s)(\w)(\w*)')

concealName.sub(lambda m: ''.join([m.group(1), # Agent
                                   m.group(2), # \s
                                   m.group(3), # first \w
                                   '*' * len(m.group(4)) # <- top secret
                                  ]), sentence)
```

which, as desired, gives `'Agent A**** tells Agent B** secret info about Agent C******.'`.

From here, try and make some improvements. E.g., there's not really a reason to have separate groups for `(Agent)`, `(\s)` and `(\w)` – you can merge them into a single group which would greatly simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```py
import re

text = "Agent Alice tells Agent Bob secret info about Agent Charlie."


def repl(match_obj):
    name = match_obj.group()
    return name[0] + "*" * (len(name) - 1)


pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=Agent )\w+")
print(pattern.sub(repl, text))
```

output:

```
Agent A**** tells Agent B** secret info about Agent C******.
```

Explanation:

The pattern `(?<=Agent )\w+`, uses a [*positive look behind*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-22) assertion so that it only matches the words (basically names) after the `"Agent "`.

Now `.sub` can accept a function as the `repl` parameter which it will call it on a found match object. Your match object is gonna be your names. The return value of this function is gonna be replaced.